# Contiuity with contracting functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, contraction-mapping

I kindly **request feedback** regarding the following proof. I am not sure about the inequalities, because of the two different metrics. What I essentially want to know is if the inequality makes sense, where i switched from $d_X$ to $d_K$? Firstly, the task is as follows:

Let $K(X)$ denote the set of contractions, i.e.,
$$K(X) = \{f: X \rightarrow X \mid \exists \kappa_f \in [0,1): d(f(x), f(y)) \leq \kappa_f d(x,y) \quad \forall x,y \in X\}.$$
We equip this set with the metric
$$d_K(f, g) = \sup_{x \in X} \{d_X(f(x), g(x))\}.$$
Let $\Phi: K(X) \rightarrow X$ be the mapping that assigns to each contraction of $X$ its unique fixed point. Determine if $\Phi$ is continuous.

Proof:

We will show $\Phi$ is contious.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$; $f, g \in K(X)$;  choose $\delta = \varepsilon$, $\delta > 0$.
Such that  $d_K(f, g) < \delta.
$Let $a_i = \Phi(i(x))$.

\begin{align*}
d_X(\Phi(f(x)), \Phi(g(x))) &= d_X(a_f, a_g) \\
&\leq \sup_{x \in X} \{d_X(f(x), g(x))\} \\
&= d_K(f, g) < \delta = \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you justify the first statement in your proof (“For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that ...”)? Also you cannnot “Set $\delta = \varepsilon$” after $\delta$ has been found.

Comment: Oh, i just noticed, that i just wrote down the definiton, did not mean too. I wrote it down for myself and forgot to write down the first part of the proof.

Comment: How do you justify $d_X(a_f, a_g) \leq \sup_{x \in X} \{d_X(f(x), g(x))\}$? – I also wonder if $d_K(f, g)$ is always defined. If we consider the functions $f(x) = c x$ with $|c| < 1$ on $X= \Bbb R$ then $d_K(f, g)$ is infinite for $f \ne g$, isn't it?

Comment: Because $d_X(a_f, a_g)=d_X(f(a_f),g(a_g))$ so the supremum is obviously greater or equal. I am not to sure about that, thats the definition we got to work with.

Comment: Perhaps $X$ is assumed to be *compact?*

Comment: all the details which were given in the task, are noted in my question